# How does one publish statsd stats for consumption by graphite?

Tags: graphite, statsd

We're just now getting to grips with statsd+graphite, and we (think we) want to look at graphs sliced differently.  For example, say we have a website `foo` that is multi-tenanted to 3 customers and served on 4 servers:

1. aggregate (all servers, all tenants) across our whole service - so publish `foo.logins.attempts:3|c`
2. aggregate by tenant (all servers) across our service - so publish `tenant1.foo.logins.attempts:3|c`
3. individual servers across our service - so publish `tenant1.server1.foo.logins.attempts:3|c`

What are the implications of

1. publishing the stats 3 times (actually, one statsd call, with one stat per line), once each with each different prefix, so it's easier to find in statsd and graphite, and manipulate
2. publishing the stat once (#3 above) and then using graphite to mix and match to produce the views that we want

?